# Replacing subsets in R with Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

How do one replace the values of a subset in R with `Tidyverse`?

Using the `cars` data as an example, if I would like to change all the `speed` lower than 30 into 0, I can use the command below:

```
 cars[cars["speed"] < 30,] <- 0
```

With `Tidyverse`, one can generate the same subset with more readable commands:

```
 cars %>% filter(speed < 30) %>% mutate(speed =0)
```

However, this is changing the subset of data we have taken out from `cars`, not the values of observations within `cars`.

I might have missed something obvious but is there an intuitive way to do the same thing with `Tidyverse` as well? While `cars[cars["speed"] < 30,] <- 0` works fine in most cases, it becomes really unwieldy when one has more than 5 conditions to meet.

Comment: i think this may be a case where the you shld not try to make everything "tidy". `replace` is just `x[list] <- values` which is pretty much what you have done and it's — IMO — just as readable and one less abstraction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the `replace` function:

```
cars %>% mutate(speed = replace(speed, speed < 30, 0))
```

An `ifelse` condition would also work:

```
cars %>% mutate(speed = ifelse(speed < 30, 0, speed))
```

I tested this on a one-million-row data frame and `replace` ran in about one-eighth the time of `ifelse`.

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(x=runif(1e6, 0, 1000), y=runif(1e6, 0, 1000))

microbenchmark(
  replace=dat %>% mutate(x=replace(x, x<200, 0)),
  ifelse=dat %>% mutate(x=ifelse(x<200, 0, x)),
  if_else=dat %>% mutate(x=if_else(x<200, 0, x)),
  times=100
)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>     expr       min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
>  replace  8.352943  9.55682  18.16755 11.45507  15.33215 224.8759   100 a  
>   ifelse 71.782371 87.37754 165.95928 95.12722 262.73016 287.3633   100   c
>  if_else 39.947845 47.83934  88.72291 51.99449  59.76760 251.0381   100  b
> ```

Comment: Really compelling comparison. Wondering how this would look if you were to use the dplyr command `if_else`.  It is supposed to be much faster than the base `ifelse`...

Comment: See updated timings. `if_else` is faster than `ifelse` but slower than `replace`.

Comment: it would be cool if there were some kind of `%<>%` analogue for `mutate`, e.g.  `cars %>% mutate(speed %=% replace(., . < 30, 0))` (I know there are plenty of reasons this would be difficult to implement, but still ...